# Read a file from web URL

Tags: typescript

I want to read a file that I have put in an S3 bucket and gave access as public. Using s3 I get the url of the file: https://tlc-test-public.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/public/member_id/xxx.txt. When I try to read this file, I am getting error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'https://tlc-test-public.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/public/member_id/xxx.txt'

```
const url = new URL('https://tlc-test-public.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/public/member_id/xxx.txt');
let stream = fs.createReadStream(url.href);

var reader = rd.createInterface({input: stream });
var lineArray: string[] = new Array;
reader.on('line', (memberId: string) => {
    lineArray.push(memberId);
    console.log(memberId);
});
```

I am expecting this to read the text file and print it in console line by line.

Comment: You are trying to read a stream from a string (`url.href`). You need to make a readable stream from an HTTP connection to the URL.

Comment: I tried this below code as well. But I need to get as a text file. Then I can read line by line. But for this below code is return buffered data.                  https.get(url.href,
  (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    res.on('data', (d) => {
      console.log(d);
    });
  }).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });